# how to pause selenium web driver for user action

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate an application where user has to enter the OTP at a particular interval . Is it possible to automate is such a way using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there should be no **Manual Intervention** when **Automated Test Execution** is **`In Pogress`**.

If entering an **OTP** is one of the step of the `Usecase` it should be automated too.

> **Note** : **OTP** can be sent to an email address and can be validated.

Answer (score 0):

If your are running the tests in Dev environment, One possible solution would be to request the developers to set a constant value for the OTP and then validate the field with the value.

More complex solution would be to get the value from message box which will include appium concepts or to read the OTP value from the mail box

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to handle this with Selenium, rely on programming language. Display a box/message, when user enters pass that to the form via selenium send keys and continue your automation. Selenium will actually wait unless your page expires. Below code can help.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String otp;   
System.out.println("Please Enter the OTP Code:: ");
otp = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Entered  OTP Code is:: "+otp);
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("otp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to enter your OTP at this page,

> www.your-page.com/OTP

once this page spawns, use `new Scanner(System.in).nextLine`

to manually wait for user-input of any key on your console. Before pressing Enter on your console, you can insert your OTP in the page (and press submit if any) after which you can resume your execution from your console by pressing any key.

This shall create a `manual-halt-like` feature during which you can perform your manual interactions.